# Using Axios and Vue.js to load JSON data

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to display JSON data on my webpage by using the v-for function in Vue.js and Axios to get the data. Below is my code and an example of the JSON data i'm trying to use.

I have kept the JSON data URL out on purpose as it's private, which is why i've provided an example of the data structure.

I can print the entire data set to my page, as it appears below but if i use my code below to print specific parts of data, like the id or name, that's when i get nothing on the page.

```
<div id="root">
        <p v-for="item in items">{{ item.name }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>

        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#root',

          data: {
            items: []
          },

          mounted() {
            axios.get("...")
            .then(response => {this.items = response.data.data})
          }

        });         

    </script>
```

JSON data example:

`json
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "83",
      "name": "Name1",
    },
    {
      "id": "78",
      "name": "Name2",
    },
    {
      "id": "720",
      "name": "Name3",
    },
    {
      "id": "707",
      "name": "Name4",
    },
    {
      "id": "708",
      "name": "Name5",
    }
  ],
  "from": 1,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 20,
  "total": 42
}`

Comment: If this.items is the same as your Json examples data it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code everything looks ok, but i have an example in the application i am working on and i've noticed that your items array should contain `response.data.data.data` wich is verbose but you can work on that later